# How to send data via socket in Android 7

Tags: android, sockets, outputstream, dataoutputstream

I'm working on an application which is able to control water station via internet and it works fine on API<24. I today we tried to installed it on new API level 24 and application suddenly stopped. I tried to figure out what was happened on this application, so I opened Android studio and traced for a few times and I got a weird error. when I tried to send a packet, application had been stopped at this line;

```
public void sendByte(final byte[] data) {
    if (outputStream == null) {
        return;
    }
    socketBusy = true;
    try {
        outputStream.write(data, 0, data.length);
        // Log.i("Log", "message Sent: " + data.toString());
        for (byte b : data) {
            Log.i("Hex format sent:  ", String.format("0x%20x", b));
        }
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I defined "outputStream" as a DataOutputStream,

```
outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

indeed it work fine on API<24 but I don't know what the problem is. even there is no massage in "Log cat" or "debug" to describe this error. 
Can somebody demonstrate how to fix this problem?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: sounds like u have fallen into a SHA support trap of Marshmallow

Comment: @Roy, what is this trap? how can I fix it? It's really urgent.

Comment: recreate ur certificates using Sha 256,since marshmallow stopped sha 1

Comment: @Roy, Can you tell me more about it. I have a keystore for this app and it has 3 encryption code, SHA1, SHA256 and MD5. where and which certificate should I change? Thanks.

Comment: change it to SHA256

Comment: 'I got a weird error' such as what?

Comment: @EJP, It'll crash without any reason on API 24 when I'm trying to send a data packet at this line " outputStream.write(data, 0, data.length);". but it works fine on API<24.
And there is no massage to identify this error or which part cause this error.

Comment: @Roy I changed the sing key SHA1 with SHA256, but it's steel not working.
Sign with:
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA256 -keystore test.keystore test.apk testkey

Comment: @Roy, I've found the problem. in API>24 app crashed because I tried to send my packet via main thread. It's sensible but I don't know why other API didn't crash.
BTW, Thanks